# TTFB is taking so long (15s-20s) for simple NextJS page in Firebase production

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, production-environment

I have a simple page that is applying SSR as follows:

```
const page = ({initProps}) => {
  // render some static texts
  // render images
};

page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // get id from ctx
  // get data from Firestore (get by id, no aggregation)
  const firebaseRes = await db.collection("organizations")
    .doc(id)
    .get();
  // return data
}
```

Currently, in the production environment, it takes around 15s for TTFB.

I tried a lot of things (use next/image, reduce the data amount returned by `getInitialProps`...) to reduce the latency time but no luck.

Is there anything else I can check/improve for my case?

==========

Add more information:

1. I run my app as a Firebase function
2. My page is a landing page (static text, static images, dynamic image loading, one Lottie animation)
3. I'm using TailwindCSS
4. My NextJS version is 12.x
5. Inside the `initialProp` function, I connect to Firestore directly to get the data.
6. Inside the `initialProp` function, besides querying the data, I have a `signInWithEmailAndPassword` to get the token.

[image]

Comment: Where are you executing this code?

Comment: Please add the following information: Where is it running? Is it a Cloud Function? What else is loading? Have you eliminated unnecessary dependencies? Is the application running in a compiled form?

Comment: Edited my post to add more information

Comment: You should explore the logs from your functions to see what takes so long in it. You can add debug console logs etc ...